# How can i get the ExtJs item from the panel if i have its name

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.2

I have the `Form Panel` and  then i have `10 form fields` in it like textbox etc.

Now i have those stored in javascript array of objects like this  `Fieldarray = []`

Now is there any way from that array i can get the each field by its name.

I want to insert those fields in different form

Something like

`NameFieldObject = getElement(fieldArray, 'firstname')`

so that i get the firstname object from that array for ExtJS elements

Answer (score 1):

While supporting existdissolve's answer, what else I can suggest you is to make **Fieldarray** an object with keys as fieldnames/ids instead of an array so that lookup will be easier.

Example:
Fieldarray = { firstName: field1, lastName: field2}

Answer (score 0):

I think you can dispense with the custom array...a form panel already has access to its own children, and has a number of built-in methods that can be used to deal with all fields, individual fields, etc.

For example, to find a particular field by name, you can simply use the findField() method, as documented here: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.Basic-method-findField